# How to have a new list for every input

Tags: python

I am trying to edit the input entered for each day. I have created an input_sales_day function that contains a number of products to enter for a day, an input_sales function that takes the number of products and days as parameters, where I think the problem lies, and a final function that just prints. I've tried using split, but I always get the error or just print each word instead.

Here is the code, it prints:

```
Product name: z1
quantity sold : 1
Product Name: z1
quantity sold : 1
Product name : z2
quantity sold : 2
Product Name: z2
quantity sold : 2
Product name : z3
quantity sold : 3
Product Name: z3
quantity sold: 3
Day 1 : ['1 z1', '1 z1']
Day 2 : ['1 z1', '1 z1', '2 z2', '2 z2']
Day 3: ['1 z1', '1 z1', '2 z2', '2 z2', '3 z3', '3 z3']
```

I try to print:

```
Day 1: ['1 z1', '1 z1']
Day 2 : ['2 z2', '2 z2']
Day 3 : ['3 z3', '3 z3']
```

```
p = []
def input_sales_day(nbp):
    for i in range(nbp):
        np = input("Product Name: ")
        qv = input("quantity sold : ")
        p.append('{} {}'.format(qv, np))
    return p

def input_sales(nbp, d):
    sl = []
    for j in range(d):
        n = input_sales_day(nbp)
        sl.append('day {} : {}'.format(j+1, n))
    return sl

def print_sales(sl):
    return '\n'.join(sl)

print(print_sales(input_sales(2, 3)))
```

Comment: If you want each day to be separate, then move the `p = []` line to INSIDE the `input_sales_day` function.  Then, each call to the function creates a new list.

Comment: oh, I spent like an hour wondering what was wrong, tried to change things and got all kinds of errors with split, also cheching an older question which is a bit similiar but didn't work :/ thank you, it's noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is make `p` a local variable of the `input_sales_day` function. If you do this, then `p` will be reset on every invokation. Like this:

```
def input_sales_day(nbp):
    p = []
    for i in range(nbp):
        np = input("Product Name: ")
        qv = input("quantity sold : ")
        p.append('{} {}'.format(qv, np))
    return p


def input_sales(nbp, d):
    sl = []
    for j in range(d):
        n = input_sales_day(nbp)
        sl.append('day {} : {}'.format(j+1, n))
    return sl


def print_sales(sl):
    return '\n'.join(sl)


print(print_sales(input_sales(2, 3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont delete the old values from the p list, so when you go for the next day, the data from the previous day is still in the list, you have to change the way to print it or delete it every day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).